# Update a field base of set of rows in Oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-update

I have a data as shown in the table (image).  The first visit of a patient should be marked as 'New' under *New_Review* column. Other visits of the same patient should be marked as 'Review' in the same column.

Also help me how to mark the first visit of a patient to a Specialisation as 'New' in another column. And other visits of the same patient to the same specialisation later as 'Review'

Thank you.

[Oracle Table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDkrU.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may define *both* columns in a *database view* only as shown on example below

```
create view v as 
select 
  REGNO, VISITDATE, SPECIALISATION,DOCID,
  /* first visit of an RegNo */
  case when row_number() over (partition by REGNO order by VISITDATE, DOCID) = 1 
       then 'New' else 'Review' end as New_Review,
  /* first visit of an RegNo for Specialisation */
  case when row_number() over (partition by REGNO, SPECIALISATION order by VISITDATE, DOCID) = 1 
       then 'New' else 'Review' end as New_Review_Spec       
from tab
```

This has **two advantages**

*First* the definition is always consistent and it need no application logic to mainatain it.

*Second* the used approach with `ROW_NUMBER` can handle also cases where you have more than one visit on the same day. See the used `ORDER BY` clause where additionally the `DOCID` is used to controll the order for visits with the same date.

Note that in the `partition by`clause you use the column(s) for which you want to define the *first visit*. In your case either `REGNO`  or `REGNO`and  `SPECIALISATION`.

The `row_number` assing the *sequence number* starting from `1`, so comparing with `1` you have your *first visit*.

Comment: Thank you so much Marmite.  This is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve it, But I think Merge statement would run fastest. So, You may try the below query -

```
MERGE INTO YOUR_TABLE T
USING (SELECT RegNo, MIN(VisitDate) First_VisitDate
         FROM YOUR_TABLE
        GROUP BY RegNo) T2
ON (T.RegNo = T2.RegNo
    AND T.VisitDate = T2.First_VisitDate)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
                     SET New_Review = 'New'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN UPDATE
                         SET New_Review = 'Review';
```

Then the same approach can be followed for the `Specialization` column.

Comment: Thank you very much Ankit.  But 'WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN UPDATE' is not working